# android load data asynchronously in view pager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I need a solution for view pager implementation.
Firstly I am loading huge data from database in single page,so sometimes during swipe it slows down swipe frequency(you need to multiple time swipe on page) as in background it is doing fetching task.
I am not using async task for returning view.
Is there any way to lazy load pages just allow user to go on other page on swipe but data is lazy loaded.

My code sample is as below;

```
 public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

View v;

v = View.inflate(context,R.layout.swipearea, null);

listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
largeDataCall();
((ViewPager)container).addView(v);
return v;
}
```

I am calling this in on create method.

```
pager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerAdapter);
pager.setAdapter(new SimplePager(MyPager.this));
pager.setCurrentItem(364);
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 17):

I would suggest to work with Fragments (and not directly with views).

You need an Interface on your fragments to tell them when they are shown:

```
public interface IShowedFragment {

    public void onShowedFragment();
}
```

Make all your fragments implement that interface, and in that method call your loaders/asyncTasks/background tasks.

Then put an onPageChangeListener on your ViewPager, and when you detect the user changed the page, call the interface method on your fragment. You have some choices with this listener, with one of the methods you can wait for the viewPager to stop to slide to trigger your interface call.

To be able to get the right fragment to make this call, take the fragment from yourFragmentApadter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int) which will return the fragment for that position if it is already  loaded.

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      Fragment fragment = (Fragment) mAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, position);
      if(fragment instanceof IShowedFragment){
           ((IShowedFragment) fragment).onShowedFragment();
      }
  }
  (...)
```

Like that you can prepare your fragments with empty views and when you slide on one, you start to load the data.

Comment: Do you have any sample implementation?

Comment: Fragments would make your life a lot easier.  If you implemented them in a fragment, then you could load the data (asynchronously) whenever you want, then display them on the Fragment's createView(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Added some implementation (what is only missing is a fragment example, where onShowedFragment() would be implemented and load your data aynchronously).

Comment: Use  setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible), it's called when you switch fragment, implemented in the adapter.

Answer (score 3):

I have just completed a very similar task. To get you started on finding the solution to your problem consider the following points in order;

1. Look at whether you need to be fetching *all* of that data in the first instance. Feel free to post back with some detail as to what information you are needing to be loaded and what you are doing with it (displaying it as a list on screen?)
2. Look at using `CursorLoader`s which perform heavy-lifting tasks such as database fetches asynchronously. [This tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/) on the interwebs introduces the ContentProvider Android approach. Best to familiarise yourself with the official Android URI and ContentProvider documentation if those terms don't mean much.
3. If you are working with Fragments - Look at using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of the traditional `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I haven't used this adapter but I have read that it only instantiates the currently visible Fragment, i.e. not those Fragments to the right or left of the currently selected tab.
4. Look at optimising the query you are running against the DB.

Comment: Agree with DeeV. This task will become easier (and more standard) if Fragments were used for each ViewPager, page. When the Fragment is to be displayed the onCreateView will be called which is where you can initialise your ````CursorLoader````s etc for async db access and seemless UI. This is certainly possible contrary to the above comments since many, many others have done it.

Answer (score 1):

`instantiateItem` is called when the `ViewPager` is about to swap and needs a view. It doesn't *have* to actually create everything.  I think ultimately, lazy-loading is out. The way I see it, there's two things you'll need to do here.

1:
Cache the data in the background when the user is about to reach your page.  Your example claims that 364 pages (good Lord), so I'd say use a listener to handle page changes.  When you're at page 363, start loading the data for 364.  When you're at 364, start loading the data at 365 and keep the data at 363 in case the user wants to swap back.  If the data loads relatively quickly or the user takes a long time to swap, it should be seemless assuming you're using asyncTask or thread to load the data.

2:  Have a backup default view that doesn't get populated until the data is retrieved.  You'll need to do this with option 1 as well in case the user loads the page before you retrieve the data.  Basically, just have a view that says "loading..." or something until you have the data.  Either that, or populate the data at real time as you get it.  In that case the user will see it build.

Either way, I think you'll need to cache something to make the app look good.

Comment: In log I can see that view pager start loading data for 363,364,365 simultaneously when I set current item to 364. so there not an issue for first load but as user swipes,say from 364 to 365 viewpager start to load data for page 366 but if data in page 366 is very high then I can see view gets freezes for few seconds.

Comment: Then that means you're loading the data synchrously for three different pages on the UI thread, two of which aren't even visible.  Also, half your job is done.  Use a thread and it should speed things up significantly.

Comment: You still need a default "not done yet" view in the event you haven't retrieved all your data when the user swipes.

Comment: But how...That's my question as if that view is returned I have to bind data later in UI thread and if I use async task if once it is skipped it shows just blank screen.

Comment: Use the `publishProgress` method in `AsyncTask` as you get a new record.  It's built for this sort of thing.  The values you pass in are the data sets you collect.  If you can't get separate records, then publish the results in `onPostExecute` which is called immediately after `doInBackground`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. A viewpager which was loading heavy data. If you are not going to change the views of the individual pages often, then I would suggest you keep the pages in memory. Use following code to perform this

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(#pages); to keep #pages in memory. I had 5 pages so my #pages was 4.
```

If you want to refresh data on the viewpager slides, use

```
mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); with getItemPosition() returning POSITION_NONE.
```

And use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's any way to lazy load data in the synchronous fashion that you describe. AsyncTask is the way to go or perhaps you could use threads directly. I believe AsyncTask was designed specifically for this kind of functionality. It's easier to use then the thread directly. If you need ideas on implementation, have a look at:
http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/

Comment: I cannot see any view pager implementation in the given link.

Comment: For view pager example you can see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html and http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html. You need to hook up this kind of implementation with AsyncTask to get optimal user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [android ignition library](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition)? according to [Sample-applications](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/wiki/Sample-applications) there is a a component "Endless List" and a http-cache component.

I havent tried it myself and dont know if this is a solution for you-just saw the examples.....