# How to move screen with data in Swipe Tabs?

Tags: android

My requierment is when I click the button in Tab1fragment ,the screen move to next screen (Tab2Fragment) and also the data I wrote in edittext.

This is my code, but not working, anyone please help me.

Tab1Fragment.java

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
            Button btSend = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final EditText editSendata =     (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Tab2Fragment fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("data",editSendata.getText().toString());
                        fragment.setArguments(args);
                    }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

tab1.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:ems="10" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Tab2Fragment.java

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment{
     private TextView txtResultData;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        this.txtResultData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        String i = getArguments().getString("data");
        txtResultData.setText(i);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

tab2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {
     private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        private ActionBar actionBar;
        // Tab titles
        private String[] tabs = { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab selected
            // show respected fragment view
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.Tab1Fragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.Tab2Fragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.Tab3Fragment;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Tab1Fragment activity
            return new Tab1Fragment();
        case 1:
            // Tab2Fragment activity
            return new Tab2Fragment();
        case 2:
            // Tab3Fragment activity
            return new Tab3Fragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

error in Log

```
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): Process: com.example.tabswithswipe, PID: 1375
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.example.tabswithswipe.Tab2Fragment.onCreateView(Tab2Fragment.java:20)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-06 03:17:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 03:17:40.870: I/Process(1375): Sending signal. PID: 1375 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You just create a new instance of Tab2Fragment in onClick method,you did nothing for changed the exsiting instance of Tab2Fragment.To figure out how to do the work, please paste some code snippets of your host activity which you add the fragments.

Comment: pls tell me how to change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703083/android-load-data-asynchronously-in-view-pagersolved
This link will help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if in the Tab2Fragment you use:

```
String i = getArguments().getString("key");
```

Comment: After I changed "key", It's also not working , the app is failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your pager adapter creates all the three `Fragment`s needed for the tabs. So the way you are setting arguments in `onClick` listener is wrong.

Try this: declare an interface in your `Tab1Fragment` and implement it in your `MainActivity` so that the call back method gets the required data from `Tab1Fragment`. How to do it is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks).

To scroll to the second tab you may have to call the `setCurrentItem()` method on the adapater of your view pager.

Get reference to `Tab2Fragment` by calling `findFragmentById` on the `FragmanetManager` instance. To do that you first have to set a tag on the fragment before returning it in your `getItem` method of adapter. After you have reference to the fragment you can call a method and send the data which can be used by the fragment to update its views.

Comment: I am new to android, so I don't understand all , can u give me more detail and code.  Thank you.